# How to find and output a type of variable?

Tags: python, variables

I'm new to Python and trying to make code that can output the variable type of an input. However, as far as I'm aware, having a variable ask for input automatically makes it a str variable.

Is there a way to have it not default to str and read correctly?

This is what I have produced:

```py
x = input("Type something:\n") #<-- this is making it a str variable
print("x = ", type(x), x)
```

For instance, if 4 is entered, the variable type is considered a str, but an int is expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

input function in python return value is a string, so x is a string var.

maybe that is what your want

```py
print("x =",type(eval(x)),x)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as elegant as your request, but there are some built in functions for string type objects you can use here, e.g. [isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric). Another approach is to use try except, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-represents-a-number-float-or-int).